# How to order by a field in a relation table with loopback

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, loopback

I have two tables with one-to-many relationship for example:

> Customer -> Orders

I want to make a query of all the customers with their respective orders ordered by a field of Order but I can't find a way to do it with loopback. This is my attempt

```
Customer.find({
  where: {
    and: [
      {or: query.where},
      {and: query.filter},
    ],
  },
  fields: ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'],
  limit: query.limit,
  skip: query.skip,
  include: [{
    relation: 'order',
    scope: {
      fields: ['id', 'name'],
    },
  }],
  order: 'order.name ASC',
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have an `order` clause on a model using a property in the relational model in loopback.